# Do all git commands have a dry-run option?

Tags: git

Do all git commands have a --dry-run option, or one which would indicate what the command would do without actually doing them?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Not every command would naturally support a dry run directly.

- git merge has [its own option](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/386/git-merge-dry-run) (`git merge --no-commit --no-ff`)
- but [git pull does not really need it](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/7/4/2350514) ('`git fetch origin`', then a
  '`git log master..origin/master`', before a `git merge origin/master`)
  (but `git push` has a dry-run option)

As [J.C. Hamano summarizes](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/11/22/4198744):

> There are things that are not implemented in git because they do not make
>   sense, and there are things that are not implemented in git because nobody
>   had itch to scratch for.
>   To put it differently, we tend to implement only
>   things that there are actual, demonstrated needs for from real world and
>   only when the addition makes sense as a coherent part of the system.

---

[iboisver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/150600/iboisver) comments:

> Another thing to be aware of is that commands like [`git add`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-add.html) and [`git rm`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-rm.html) allow the **`-n` command-line option to specify dry run**, while in [`git commit`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-commit.html), the `-n` option means something completely different.
>   So be sure to check the man page

`git commit -n`:

```
-n
--no-verify
```

> This option bypasses the pre-commit and commit-msg hooks. See also [githooks(5)](http://schacon.github.com/git/githooks.html).

Comment: Another thing to be aware of is that commands like `git-add` and `git-rm` allow the _-n_ command-line option to specify dry run, while in `git-commit`, the _-n_ option means something completely different. So be sure to check the man page.

Comment: @iboisver interesting feedback, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: I would have wanted --dry-run on "git stash", especially when pushing a directory "git stash push -- /dir"

Comment: @GaurangPatel Agreed. That was discussed in 2017 here: https://public-inbox.org/git/CA+CzEk8QiSu4heMDsx7XC729UEPNm6hdZfs9W5uwoJBvuLWr+w@mail.gmail.com/

Answer (score 14):

While there isn't always a `--dry-run` flag for every comment, there are usually equivalents. For example, [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option) shows what to do for `git merge`.

Comment: there is none for `rebase`, for one example.