# Is there any way to know the files that will be used in a given GIT operation under windows?

Tags: windows, git, command-line

I'm a windows / svn person trying to learn to use GIT by command line. I'm using a basic add . /commit/push cycle, and I typically try to add all changed files, so I don't care. But every once in a while I want to add just some of the changed files. I don't enjoy typing the usually long full paths (java....) and I know I could use characters like * to match multiple files... but I found no way to know in advance what files will be affected.
As an example, if I make a `git status`, I got 3 files,

```
   modified:   myrepo/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/helper/WordBuilder.java
   modified:   myrepo/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/helper/WordBuyer.java
   modified:   myrepo/src/main/java/com/mycompany/myproject/helper/WordDeleter.java
```

I want to add just files WordBuilder and WordBuyer, so instead of typing `git add .`
I want to type something that matches them and excludes WordDeleter (example is not great)
. Lest say I want to try `git add WordB*`, I want to know before actually typing it what files will be added to be sure I'm not omitting or including anything by mistake.
Is this possible?
EDIT: More details I forgot: I'm using Windows7, GIT command line  via [msysGit/GIT for windows](http://msysgit.github.io/)

Comment: This is not a `git` question, but rather a shell question, since `git` receives whatever list of files results from the shell's expansion of the glob. What shell are you using? (I've gotten the impression that some Windows implementations of `git` merge it and a shell into a single program, so the line between the two may be somewhat blurred).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `--dry-run` to most of git command to not doing the action, but displaying instead what will be done.

`git add --dry-run WordB*` should work. check with help command to check the help for others actions

Comment: Seems to be working. I worry about the 'most of' part.... I hope the ones that does not work show an error message! thanks you!

Comment: yeah, "most of" because for example, --dry-run is nonsense for git fetch. But this is ok for `commit` and `add`. checks that question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573905/do-all-git-commands-have-a-dry-run-option for more details

Answer (score -1):

```
echo WordB*
```

would show you the expansion without involving git.