# Git: preview / simulate / undo changes to repository

Tags: git

My repository graph looks like spaghetti, mainly due to mistakes with pushing, merging, and so on. I make mistakes more often than I get things right. And there doesn't seem to be an 'undo' functionality, at least not one which is more complicated (and dangerous) than what got me into a mess in the first place.

**Are there any git-for-dummies applications that protect a user from his own stupidity? E.g. a dead-simple "undo" functionality, or a feature that allows you to preview a series of changes, and if the result is as desired, that series of actions can be executed?**

I'm using Git Extensions at the moment which seems to be the most intuitive for me, but nevertheless. I have a 'test' repository that I use to test actions to make sure the commands I'm about to run do what I think they'll do, but it can take a long time setting things up to be the same as my project's repository that I tend not to bother; and when I do bother, for one reason or another it doesn't always seem to work out the same.

Comment: You don't say what platform you are on, but on Mac, the Gitup application has a nice undo feature called snapshots. It's sort of like Time Machine, but for git. http://forums.gitup.co/t/using-gitup-snapshots/18

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commands that directly work on the repository graph (`merge`, `push` and `pull`) feature a [`--dry-run` option (or an equivalent)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573905/do-all-git-commands-have-a-dry-run-option) which allows you to preview and check the changes before "committing" to them.

In the worst case if you messed something up, there's *always* the option of using `git reset --hard` to force your HEAD to a certain point in the tree.

Comment: Interesting to know, thanks. I just wish GUIs made better use of that feature. Hopefully I will find a good one that does

Answer (score 0):

As all Git tutorials say - **branches are cheap**. This means you could use them as a backup tool. Everytime you're not sure what's gonna happen, create a new branch from your current state (`git checkout -b new_branch_name`) and experiment on it.