# JGit Check Permissions

Tags: java, jgit

In JGit, is it possible to check developer permissions without doing the actions (provided username and password)?

Ex: Is it possible to check if a user can clone a repository without cloning it?

Ex2: Is it possible to check if a user can push to a repository without pushing to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Ex1

I think, this is not supported by `git` itself, so **no**. (I might be wrong though)

As a workaround, one might use `CloneCommand#setNoCheckout(boolean)` [1], which prevents downloading any branch (clone command should be pretty quick). The cloned repository (cloned into some temp directory), might be removed immediately, if call succeeded.

## Ex2

For push, `dry-run` can be used. Supported by JGit [2].

Most of the commands have some form of `dry-run` option.

See: [Do all git commands have a dry-run option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573905/do-all-git-commands-have-a-dry-run-option)

--

[1] https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/latest/org.eclipse.jgit/org/eclipse/jgit/api/CloneCommand.html

[2] https://javadoc.io/doc/org.eclipse.jgit/org.eclipse.jgit/latest/org.eclipse.jgit/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommand.html

Comment: A --dry-run doesn't send the commands the client would use from client to server, therefore permissions will not be checked server side.