# Why can I not switch branches?

Tags: git, xcode4

I'm trying to switch branches in git but I'm getting this error message:

```
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

I'm using git under xcode4

```
git status
# On branch DateCode
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#
#   both modified:      Whereami.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdatauser.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Frappuccinos-MacBook-Pro:whereami
```

Comment: # Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
#

Comment: please edit your question to paste that information, it's unreadable in comments.

Comment: `git reset {{currentBranchName}}` then `git checkout .`  will solve your problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git merge errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006737/git-merge-errors)

Answer (score 103):

Try this if you don't want any of the merges listed in git status:

```
git reset --merge
```

This resets the index and updates the files in the working tree that are different between `<commit>` and `HEAD`, but keeps those which are different between the index and working tree (i.e. which have changes which have not been added).

If a file that is different between `<commit>` and the index has unstaged changes -- reset is aborted.

More about this - https://www.techpurohit.in/list-some-useful-git-commands & Doc link - https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset

Answer (score 53):

You end up with `both modified` in the output of `git status` if there were conflicts produced by a merge.  git isn't letting you change branch until you've resolved these conflicts.  If you edit that file, you should see some conflict markers in it - there's a [guide to resolving those conflicts in the git manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge).  (Since kernel.org is currently down,  you can find that guide [here](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge) instead.)

Alternatively, if you think the merge was a mistake, you could undo it with: `git reset --merge`

Answer (score 25):

If you don't care about the changes that git says are outstanding, then you can do a force checkout.

`git checkout -f {{insert your branch name here}}`

Comment: This was exactly what I needed -- I had a test branch where a merge had failed with lots of conflicts, and I just wanted to throw away the branch. I wasn't able to get back to a good branch (checkout failed, and `git reset --merge` also failed). But `checkout -f` worked great.

Answer (score 6):

I got this message when updating new files from remote and index got out of whack. Tried to fix the index, but resolving via Xcode 4.5, GitHub.app (103), and GitX.app (0.7.1) failed.  So, I did this:

```
git commit -a -m "your commit message here"
```

which worked in bypassing the git index.

Two blog posts that helped me understand about Git and Xcode are:

[Ray Wenderlich on Xcode 4.5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6) and

[Oliver Steele from 2008](http://osteele.com/posts/2008/05/my-git-workflow)

Answer (score 6):

you can reset your branch with HEAD

```
git reset --hard branch_name
```

then fetch branches and delete branches which are not on remote from local,

```
git fetch -p
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit or destroy any unsaved changes before you switch branch.

Git won't let you switch branch if it means unsaved changes would be removed.

Comment: The error and the `git status` output indicate that this isn't just changes in the working tree that would be lost by changing branch -- they indicate that a merge failed and the conflicts must be resolved in the index.

Answer (score 1):

Since the file is modified by both, Either you need to add it by

```
git add Whereami.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdatauser.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

Or if you would like to ignore yoyr changes, then do

```
git reset HEAD Whereami.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdatauser.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
```

After that just switch your branch.This should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Git says you have unresolved merge conflicts in your current branch. Ideally you should resolve the merge conflicts, and then commit the changes.

BUT, IF you really don't care about the local changes in current branch (maybe you were trying out something locally, but need not persist them), you can ignore and force checkout the other branch

```
git checkout -f <other-branch-name>
```

IF you'd still want the first branch (with merge conflict) but just want the latest from remote, you can do this

- Force delete that branch
- Fresh checkout the branch

```bash
# assuming you already switched to another branch

git branch -D <branch-to-reset>
git fetch
git checkout <branch-to-reset>
```