# Git merge errors

Tags: git, branch, git-merge, git-branch

I have a git branch called `9-sign-in-out` with perfectly working code, and I want to turn it into the master. I'm currently on the master branch.

```
$ git branch
9-sign-in-out
* master
```

I'm trying to switch to `9-sign-in-out` branch, but it doesn't allow me to:

```
$ git checkout 9-sign-in-out
app/helpers/application_helper.rb: needs merge
config/routes.rb: needs merge
error: you need to resolve your current index first
```

Any idea how can I ignore all the master branch errors and turn the `9-sign-in-out` branch into the master? Maybe git [rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase)? But I don't want to lose the code in `9-sign-in-out` branch.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want to lose your uncomitted code in 9-sign-in-out?

Comment: @Mauvis: I already committed my codes in the branch 9-sign-in-out.

Answer (score 723, accepted):

It's worth understanding what those error messages mean - `needs merge` and `error: you need to resolve your current index first` indicate that a merge failed, and that there are conflicts in those files.  If you've decided that whatever merge you were trying to do was a bad idea after all, you can put things back to normal with:

```
git reset --merge
```

However, otherwise you should resolve those merge conflicts, [as described in the git manual](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge).

---

Once you've dealt with that by either technique you should be able to checkout the `9-sign-in-out` branch.  The problem with just renaming your `9-sign-in-out` to `master`, as suggested in [wRAR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6006737/git-merge-errors/6006775#6006775) is that if you've shared your previous master branch with anyone, this will create problems for them, since if the history of the two branches diverged, you'll be publishing rewritten history.

Essentially what you want to do is to merge your topic branch `9-sign-in-out` into `master` but exactly keep the versions of the files in the topic branch.  You could do this with the following steps:

```
# Switch to the topic branch:
git checkout 9-sign-in-out

# Create a merge commit, which looks as if it's merging in from master, but is
# actually discarding everything from the master branch and keeping everything
# from 9-sign-in-out:
git merge -s ours master

# Switch back to the master branch:
git checkout master

# Merge the topic branch into master - this should now be a fast-forward
# that leaves you with master exactly as 9-sign-in-out was:
git merge 9-sign-in-out
```

Comment: Mark, I finally understood what you were saying after I got the error again to merge now. I'm, however having this error::::::::::::: Sayanee:twitter sweska$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
 webrat.log
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting::::::::::::::::: any way, to user the webrat.log in the branch and make it merge with the master?

Comment: @Sayanee: that's a different error, arising from different circumstances, and it would be better to ask a new question about that if you're confused by it.  (Briefly, though, git's stopping you from switching branches since that would overwrite uncommitted changes in `webrat.log`.)

Comment: I used to just rm the whole thing and reclone. But this is nicer.

Answer (score 57):

Change branch, discarding all local modifications

```
git checkout -f 9-sign-in-out
```

Rename the current branch to master, discarding current master

```
git branch -M master
```

Comment: I think its much cleaner to reset the merge like Mark suggested below instead of forcing the checkout.

Answer (score 13):

as suggested in `git status`,

```
Unmerged paths:                                                                                                                                
(use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)                                                                                                 

    both modified:   a.jl                                  
    both modified:   b.jl
```

I used `git add` to finish the merging, then `git checkout` works fine.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when switching from a dev branch to master branch. What I did was commit my changes and switch to the master branch. You might have uncommitted changes.

And also you can try this `git reset --merge` as well. This can be used to resolve any conflicts and revert.

Answer (score 5):

I got this when using GitHub Desktop when trying to switch from a dev branch to master, even after I had resolved all merge conflicts.

After typing `git add *` on the command line it allowed me to switch branches again.

Answer (score 2):

my issue was (master|REBASE 1/1)

this command worked for me

```
 git rebase --skip
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the exact scenario described in the question. It answers the following scenario which you end up with the same error messages. Posting here because this SO link comes up first when Googling for this.

---

This usually happens for **GitHub Desktop** users.

If you made changes locally on a branch that's deleted in remote, then merged from master, and already resolved conflicts, and now you cannot move your changes to any other branch because of the;

`you need to resolve your current index first`,
and `needs merge` error,

simply do below:

```
# unset the upstream which is deleted 
- git branch --unset-upstream
# rename the branch
- git branch -m <newname>
```

From here you can do the usual.

Answer (score -10):

git commit -m "Merged master fixed conflict."