# git: error: you need to resolve your current index first

Tags: git, git-merge

I was trying to merge a branch with my branch, but had merge conflicts.

After seeing the conflicts, I've decided to revert my branch, but am unsure how to do so, as my usual approach of running the following doesnt seem to work to reset my branch

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/BRANCH
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-merge%5D+abort

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Found out you can abort your merge using:

`$ git reset --merge`

from [this similar question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6007083/26510)

Comment: Keep in mind (and I know this will be obvious to some people), this will clear you existing changes.