# Error trying to update oh-my-zsh I have already removed yarn, and continue

Tags: oh-my-zsh

Error trying to update oh-my-zsh I have already removed yarn, and continue... I researched, but I couldn't solve it, has anyone experienced the same problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omyQx.png)

Answer (score 12):

Your repository of `oh-my-zsh` have some file modified (it's a git repository).  You can do:

1. `cd "$ZSH"` or `cd ~/.oh-my-zsh/` to access the root folder of zsh
2. `git add .` to add all files (modified/included) as staged
3. `git stash -m "your message"` to put all files modified/included in stash, it will clean the repository, but you can catch all the files later.
4. `omz update` or `upgrade_oh_my_zsh` to upgrade the zsh

After the update you can catch the files that are added in the stash (if you needs) with `git stash apply` (the stash will be there still) or `git stash pop` (the stash will be removed)

**Note:** Apply your stash after the update can produce some local conflicts.

[reference of my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/923347/why-does-updating-oh-my-zsh-give-me-an-error-about-rebasing-with-unstaged-change)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Git warning message - did you changed something down the ".oh-my-zsh" directory ? Especially in the "yarn" subdirectory ?

This Stackoverflow question should help to recover :  [git: error: you need to resolve your current index first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57044187/git-error-you-need-to-resolve-your-current-index-first)

Comment: I don't remember making changes, whenever I open the terminal and have the option to update, I authorize it, and I never had any problems. But this time this error happened, I was surprised to see that it was something from git. I don't know how to solve it. I went to the .oh-my-zsh directory and saw that there is no yarn directory in plugins