# How to tell if my git repo is in a conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

Are there commands I can call programatically to determine whether my git repo is in the state of each of

1. merge conflict
2. rebase conflict
3. conflict due to stash pop

In particular I want to know whether I can programmatically issue `git merge --abort` (inthe case of 1) and `git rebase --abort` (in the case of 2) to get back to a known good state.

Answer (score 1):

1. During a merge, the files `MERGE_HEAD`, `MERGE_MODE` and `MERGE_MSG` exist in your `.git` folder.
2. During a rebase, a `rebase-apply` folder exists inside your `.git` folder. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921409/how-to-know-if-there-is-a-git-rebase-in-progress) and its answers.
3. `stash pop` performs a merge, but not really. The contents of the `.git` folder seem to be as usual. I'm not entirely sure, but since a merge from stash cannot be aborted (something like `git stash pop --abort` cannot be done, and if you want to abort you have to go with good ol' `git reset --hard HEAD`), I do not think the repository is in a real "conflict state". All you have are the conflict markers in the conflicted files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Regarding 3, I have just set up a repo with a simple `stash pop` conflict and none of the `MERGE` files actually exist.

Comment: Edited my answer, but still not entirely sure if there isn't a better way for 3.

Comment: There must be something different in `.git` because if I try to `checkout` to a different branch I get `error: you need to resolve your current index first`.

Comment: I guess the relevant info is stored in `.git/index`, but I don't know how to parse that file.  It seems to be binary.

Comment: `checkout HEAD` seems to be a good way to distinguish `stash pop` conflict from no conflict.

Comment: `error: you need to resolve your current index first` This is shown because there are files that are shown as "both modified", i.e. contain conflict markers. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31697708/7598462) shows how to reset the files, which would be analog to "abort" the merge in 1.

Comment: Thank's that's interesting!  Do you agree with my use of `git checkout HEAD` to detect `stash pop` conflict, or do you know a better way?

Comment: `git checkout HEAD` does inform you about conflicted files, yes. You can get the same information from `git status`: it shows conflicted files in the `unmerged paths` section. Both seem to be legit ways to check for conflicted files.