# How to list files (from two different branches) that conflict?

Tags: git, git-merge

AFAIK, `git diff` shows all differences between commits, including those that would not result in a `merge` conflict.

Is there a way to list *only* those files in branch `otherbranch` that would have a conflict if I were to run `git merge otherbranch`?  Is there a way to list the actual conflicts (in some `diff`-like format)?

Comment: What about `git merge <branch> --no-commmit --no-ff` followed by `git status`?

Comment: Related: (1) [Can git tell me if a merge will conflict without actually merging?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6335717/456814), (2) [What's the simplest way to git a list of conflicted files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3065650/456814). It looks like there are a few similar ones to those laying around too.

Comment: @kjo in case you were wondering, no, I didn't downvote this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to list only those files in branch otherbranch that would have a conflict if I were to run git merge otherbranch?

When you run `git merge` or `git rebase` you can get back to the state you were before running `git reset --merge` (or `git merge --abort` since 1.7.4)  or `git rebase --abort`.

At this point you can list files with
`git diff --name-status --diff-filter=U` command

> Is there a way to list the actual conflicts (in some diff-like format)?

There are many ways to have a 3-way merge view if you want a smart way to see and edit the merge conflicts, it depends on your favourite evironment setup.

In example with VIM you can bind this two commands in your gitconfig

> edit-unmerged = \
>       "!f() { git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u ; }; vim `f`"
>
> add-unmerged = \
>       "!f() { git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u ; }; git add `f`"

And handle 3-way merge with this method
[Fugitive.vim - resolving merge conflicts with vimdiff](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/fugitive-vim-resolving-merge-conflicts-with-vimdiff/)