# Git id not showing any conflicts for binary files

Tags: git, github, git-plumbing

We are checking in binary files into git. The problem is git does not shows conflicts/changes while merging. It just accepts the file and overwrites it even there are conflicts. I am not sure whether git understands binary files or not. Please help and provide suggestions.

Note: Binary files are generated from our own tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the binary files are generated, they should not be put in the git repo in the first place.

When merging, there will be a conflict only if the binary file has been update in *both* branches (the source and the destination branches of the merge). In that case, as shown in "[Resolving a Git conflict with binary files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/278081/6309)", there will be a conflict.

If the binary file has been updated only in the source branch, then it will overwrite the same file in the destination branch of the merge.

Comment: Hello Vonc, I have my own jar to read that binary file. Is there any way to utilize the jar and show conflict before merge. Mainly can i write any plugin to understand the binary file using my jar?

Comment: @KarthikeyanV for testing a merge: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6335717/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/501407/6309. For example `git merge --no-commit --no-ff $BRANCH`

Comment: @KarthikeyanV generally, binaries are not merged (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2920807/6309)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your comments were very helpful.