# Resume chained commands after resolved merge conflict

Tags: git

I'm trying to write an alias `up` for git which does the following

1. Stash changes to current branch `foo`
2. Checkout master
3. Fetch/Pull
4. Checkout `foo`
5. `git merge master`
6. Restore stashed changes

```
up = !git stash save masterupdate && git checkout master && git fetch && git pull && git checkout @{-1} && git merge master && git stash pop stash^{/masterupdate}
```

This works unless there is a merge conflict that needs to be resolved. In such cases, it stops at the conflict step and I need to manually apply the stash.

- How can I make it so upon resolving the merge conflict the rest of the chained commands would continue as normal again?
- Is the only option to make a second alias for this case?
- Can the stash messages be squelched in the case of no change?

---

My workflow involves making pull requests which then get reviewed by other team members, rebasing is not an option as it would destroy their comments

Comment: Consider the following approch: check if merge can be done auto without conflict, only then start it - otherwise prompt message about the conflict to the user and don't start your flow.. Github act like this in pull request. Check this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6335717/can-git-tell-me-if-a-merge-will-conflict-without-actually-merging

Answer (score 0):

As far as the question:

> How can I make it so upon resolving the merge conflict the rest of the
>   chained commands would continue as normal again?

You can't. Because the merge fails it stops the shell executing of your cli.

You could write a shell script that does the same thing with some checks to see if you ran the script a 2nd/3rd time so it would skip straight to your `git stash pop stash^{/masterupdate}`
If you name the script git-something, you can actually run your command like `git something` and you could create an alias calling `git something`