# How to detect conflict between two git repositories.

Tags: git, pull-request, grit

To implement github like fork/pull request function in my project, the auto-merge feature need to detect conflict between source/target repository every time while viewing the pull request.

One solution comes to me is to analyze the 'git request-pull' output. Is there any easier method to detect the conflict?

Comment: What is being asked here? Are you implementing a merge tool? Or a diff-viewing tool? Or simply curious what `git push` is going to do?

Comment: In github, a non-conflict pull request can be merged just by click a button on web. Since the source/target repository could keep on committing, a detection of conflict is a must in this process. I'm asking a easier way to detect the conflict.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I wrote my own function to detect conflict.

It is quite simple, just fetch all diff lines, and compare if there is same modifications.

Comment: It would be great to post it here for future reference

Answer (score 3):

I have deleted my previous answer, I didn't understand the question ...

Now here's the shiny new answer:

```
git merge --ff-only <branch>
```

If there are no conflicts, it will do a merge. With a conflict, it gives you a message: `Not possible to fast-forward`. The console return code (echo $?) is 128 in this situation.

Comment: This is not relevant much to the question, but is good while merging after fetch.

Answer (score 1):

We've created a git-conflict-detector that check the latest pushed commit vs all existing branches.

It's a simple single script that is initiated by GitHub WebHook URL and even know to sent an HiChat notification when conflict is detected.

We based our solution on analyzing the `git merge --ff-only <branch>` output as you can see [here](https://github.com/sortex/git-conflict-detector/blob/master/detect_conflicts.php#L101)

We've open source it so all can enjoy, learn and contribute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't find out if a merge would produce conflicts until you actually merge these branches.

This was already pointed out in: [How to test a merge without actually merging first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484199/git-merge-test-first).

So, to answer your question, if you need to implement this kind of feature, you should most likely try to merge your source/target and rollback the merging action (using `git reset --hard`).

I never used `git request-pull`, but looking at the output, I don't see any information which could help you resolve your problem. You could probably get the same result using `git diff`, `git wtf`, `git remote show <name>`.

References:

- `git wtf` : https://github.com/michaelklishin/git-wtf
- `git request-pull` : http://progit.org/book/ch5-2.html

Answer (score 0):

For the record, there is `git merge-tree` that can tell you on cmdline if two commits aka. branches aka. pull requests conflict without touching index or working tree:

```
$> git merge-tree 9e451918b3bb56f857c6f6df5d527092c02b2b3a  b246935
60633013298d0dc97cde3738a378228b24e2b065
100644 88c2893ef8df18fd38034deab08cfee24dfb26fe 2       file1
100644 257cc5642cb1a054f08cc83f2d943e56fd3ebe99 3       file1

Auto-merging file1
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in file1
```

Of course you have to have both fetched.

The Github API seems not be too responsive on this question. A [PR can tell if it has merge conflicts](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/rest/pulls/pulls#get-a-pull-request) with base branch. Also two [commits can be compared](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.6/rest/commits/commits#compare-two-commits), but that tells you only the diff or patch, but not if it has a conflict. There seems to be no API to evaluate if two pulls or branches or commits would conflict, although Github certainly has all required information in its db. I didn't try, but I assume that when you get the patch infos from github you can run `patch --dry-run` to see if this conflicts.