# Git GUI tool to show incoming changes for conflicted files

Tags: git, git-merge-conflict

When I delete a file, which was modified on another branch; then I merge that branch, I end up with a conflict saying `CONFLICT (modify/delete): ..file.. deleted in HEAD and modified in ..other-branch..`
In this case - but **only** in this case - TortoiseGit shows this window:
[image: TortoiseGit's Show changes]

The `Show changes` button shows the **incoming changes** of the conflicted file - aka the changes it had on the other branch.

This is a very useful feature.
It would be great to have this feature for **all kind of conflicts**.

There are 46 GIT GUI client tools listed here:
https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis

From them, I use every day: TortoiseGit, SourceTree, Fork. And of course the GIT CLI.

How to get the incoming changes of a conflicted file in these clients, or in any other GIT client available?
I'm also open for a CLI alias if no GUI client can do this.

## [Edit] Example use case

For example I move a code block from file1 to file2.
On the other branch, that code block was modified in file1.

file1.js

```
...

function myFunction() {
    ...
}
```

I move this code blokk into file2.js, thus I delete it from file1.js.

On the other branch, `myFunction` gets modified like this:

file1.js

```
...
const aVariableWhichWontConflict = calcIt(...)

function myFunction() {
    ...
    useIt(aVariableWhichWontConflict)
    ...
}
```

I only will get merge conflict within `myFunction`, the line `const aVariableWhichWontConflict = calcIt(...)` will be merged into file1 without conflict.
I will have to detect this change and move it into file2 as well.

The example above is simple and easy, but in real life these could be much more complicated.
To be able to see the **incoming changes of file1** in one diff would help a lot with these kind of merges.

Comment: In CLI, you could try `git merge-tree`. http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-merge-tree

Comment: I myself have very little use for GUIs at all, but you can synthesize any of these using Git's *index* during a conflicted merge: the three copies of the conflicted files are in index slots 1, 2, and 3 for merge base, ours, and theirs respectively. Using `git checkout-index --stage=all` or similar gets you all three files. For modify/delete conflicts, one slot is empty (ours or theirs).

Comment: I added an example use case. I could not find out the usage of `git merge-tree`, @ElpieKay could you please provide an exmaple? @torek I tried `git checkout-index --stage=all` but nothing happened. What I need would be to diff the incoming version of say `file1.js` to the merge-base version of `file1.js`, right?

Comment: Sorry but this question seems to have morphed in a confusing way. Is the question now how to diff the incoming branch's `file1.js` with the merge base's `file1.js`? Because that's easy. It's just a diff like any other. Are we assuming here that you are paused at a merge conflict?

Comment: I realized now the incoming changes of the conflicted `file1.js` are actually the diff between the incoming branch's `file1.js` and the merge base's `file1.js`. Diffing them is easy, so my problem is resolved by manually diffing these. However, it still would be great to have this as a feature of a GIT GUI tool. Like the TortoiseGit `Show changes` button above, available for every kind of merge conflicts. If anyone knows of such GIT GUI tool, please share it with me :)

Answer (score 1):

> I could not find out the usage of `git merge-tree`, could you please provide an example?

Since [Git 2.38 (Q3 2022)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091924/6309), you would use:

```
git merge-tree --write-tree --no-messages --name-only branch1 branch2
```

That would preview the filenames that would be in conflict in a merge.

---

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), "[`git merge-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c662038629a5fb9b604df0f4ae5d812799de52fe/Documentation/git-merge-tree.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-tree))</sup> learned to take strategy backend specific options via the `-X` option, like "[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c662038629a5fb9b604df0f4ae5d812799de52fe/Documentation/git-merge.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup> does.

See [commit b182658](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b182658e3ed412e21a472db42ebc37130cee68e0) (11 Oct 2023) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 6a4c9e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a4c9e7b32c4154345785bd7b8d4afee5fddcead) (24 Sep 2023) by [Tang Yuyi (`WingT`)](https://github.com/WingT).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c662038](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c662038629a5fb9b604df0f4ae5d812799de52fe), 20 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`merge-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6a4c9e7b32c4154345785bd7b8d4afee5fddcead): add `-X` strategy option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Tang Yuyi</sup>

> Add merge strategy option to produce more customizable merge result such as automatically resolving conflicts.

So now a `git merge-tree -X ours side1 side2` is possible.