# git - easy way to merge 3 trees without touching index or working tree

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a rather devilish idea in my head that requires me to run different merge operations where I do *not* want to touch the index nor the working tree. I know about `git merge-tree` that I think used to do what I am requesting but it has been obsoleted (at least the possibility of providing the 3 trees and getting the resulting tree id as output). Are there other current ways to do it?

Just to be clear:

- I do not want to mess up with histories.
- I want to provide the base tree and the 2 tip trees.
- And last but not least, I do **not** want to mess up with the index nor the working tree.

All I need as output is the resulting tree id if merge succeeds.... if there are conflicts it's ok that I get nothing.

Comment: There's some ongoing work on this right now, but unless you want to hack on the Git internals, the thing to do is use a temporary working tree and index, it's a lot easier that way... (For the ongoing work, see the Git mailing list.)

Comment: Understand.... will go into the archives to see how it is going and to keep an eye on it. Is there a thread that stands out on this?

Comment: Not sure about "stands out" but start with [the most recent here](https://marc.info/?l=git&m=166729251919413&w=2), and/or look for the corresponding topic in Junio's tree (not sure where one finds that).

Comment: Actually, that look _a lot_ like what I am missing at the time from `git merge-tree`. I guess I can wait a little bit until it reaches main.

Comment: This is a third (?) go-around on some ideas that are getting shoved in various directions, so there's no telling when it might actually get into `next`, much less master/main.

Comment: ok. Will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While `git merge-tree` [already improved with Git 2.37/2.38](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091924/6309), only Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) adds the missing part you seek: "`merge-tree`" learns a new `--merge-base` option.

See [commit 4cc9eb3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4cc9eb338d8773b4c3909368445404745f94ce69) (24 Nov 2022), and [commit 501e3ba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/501e3bab99da75eada3e2d6ef5257a3c44dd1ae4), [commit 66265a6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66265a693e8deb3ab86577eb7f69940410044081) (11 Nov 2022) by [Kyle Zhao (`yefengzkk`)](https://github.com/yefengzkk).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7576e51](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7576e512cec7630ba2a35af33fa00868cedb8e18), 14 Dec 2022)</sup>

> ### [`merge-tree.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66265a693e8deb3ab86577eb7f69940410044081): add --merge-base= option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kyle Zhao</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> This patch will give our callers more flexibility to use [`git merge-tree`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/66265a693e8deb3ab86577eb7f69940410044081/Documentation/git-merge-tree.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#Documentation/git-merge.txt-tree))</sup>, such as:
>
> ```
> git merge-tree --write-tree --merge-base=branch^ HEAD branch
> ```
>
> This does a merge of HEAD and branch, but uses branch^ as the merge-base.
>
> And the reason why using an option flag instead of a positional argument is to allow additional commits passed to merge-tree to be handled via an octopus merge in the future.

Note: Specifying multiple bases is currently not supported

And:

> ### [`merge-tree.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/501e3bab99da75eada3e2d6ef5257a3c44dd1ae4): allow specifying the merge-base when --stdin is passed
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Kyle Zhao</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> The previous commit added a `--merge-base` option in order to allow using a specified merge-base for the merge.
> Extend the input accepted by `--stdin` to also allow a specified merge-base with each merge requested.
> For example:
>
> ```
> printf "<b3> -- <b1> <b2>" | git merge-tree --stdin
> ```
>
> does a merge of `b1` and `b2`, and uses `b3` as the merge-base.

`git merge-tree` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/501e3bab99da75eada3e2d6ef5257a3c44dd1ae4/Documentation/git-merge-tree.txt#L224-L234):

> ### INPUT FORMAT
>
> '`git merge-tree --stdin`' input format is fully text based. Each line
> has this format:
>
> ```
> [<base-commit> -- ]<branch1> <branch2>
> ```
>
> If one line is separated by `--`, the string before the separator is
> used for specifying a merge-base for the merge and the string after
> the separator describes the branches to be merged.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @VonC. I had been keeping an eye on the patch, just not every day. Good to know it made it to `main`.