# How do I see how many conflicts a git merge will cause

Tags: git

How can I see how many conflicts will result from a merge without actually performing the merge?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a git-merge --dry-run option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to run the merge, and then abort if it didn't work.  There really isn't any other way, because it requires the working directory.

You can stash your local changes, though, and you can easily discard the incomplete merge with `git reset --hard HEAD`, so as not to lose changes or whatever.

You can also use a new, throw-away branch to work out how much conflict there is without risking any of the current, active branches.