# How to check merge conflicts of two branches, without merging them?

Tags: git

I can't merge two branches because of a release step of our project, but I want to know whether there are merge conflicts between them. How can I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a git-merge --dry-run option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option)

Comment: There's a lot more discussion on the question mentioned by @ks1322 and some alternative approaches, and it does seem to be the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Suppose you are on the `master` branch and you would like to test if the `dev` branch can be merged without conflict into the `master`.

```
# In the master branch
git merge dev --no-ff --no-commit
```

After that, you will be able to know if there's a conflict or not.

To return in a normal situation, just abort the merge:

`git merge --abort`

According to the git documentation:

> **`--ff`**
>   Do not generate a merge commit if the merge resolved as a fast-forward, only update the branch pointer. This is the default behavior.
>
> **`-no-ff`**
>   Generate a merge commit even if the merge resolved as a fast-forward.
>
> **`--commit`**
>   Perform the merge and commit the result. This option can be used to override --no-commit.
>
> **`--no-commit`**
>   With --no-commit perform the merge but pretend the merge failed and do not autocommit, to give the user a chance to inspect and further tweak the merge result before committing.

Comment: I have come to this solution so many times and I know I will keep coming! It works like charm.

Comment: See also this great answer to a very similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6283843

Comment: In case it's not obvious, if you want to accept the merge after all, instead of using `--abort` you can `commit` instead. If there are conflicts you will need to fix those first by editing the files that are listed with conflicts and using `git add` to add the modified files to the commit. The default commit message offered is the same usual default merge message.

Answer (score 2):

Providing an answer based on a use case - you are on a feature branch - working on a change. Meanwhile another colleague makes changes on a shared file and merges into trunk. Now you are ready to merge. At this point you will have the issue of merge conflict.

Ensure you have latest version of trunk branch

```
git fetch
git checkout trunk
git pull
```

Switch back to feature branch

```
git checkout feature
```

In the feature branch, simulate merge into trunk branch as a fast forward (--no-ff). The --no-commit will prevent a autocommit

```
git merge trunk --no-ff --no-commit
```

Inspect the files.

- The lines between [<<<<<<< HEAD] and [=======] are the ones in
  feature branch
- The lines between [=======] and [>>>>>>> trunk] are
  the ones in trunk branch

To abort the simulated merge and go back to your original state, run

```
git merge --abort
```

Comment: Basically the same answer as the one from 3 years earlier except with less information about the specifics of the actual original question.