# How do I git merge a branch that has already resolved conflicts with master?

Tags: git, version-control, merge, git-merge

I have a branch that is currently at the same commit as `master`. Another developer has just merged `master` into their branch and resolved all conflicts, but they have NOT done the opposite yet: merge their branch into master.

When I merge their branch into mine I still get all the conflicts that they resolved in their last merge commit. How can I tell git to use the resolutions that the other developer has already done?

Comment: I may have found an answer, but I'm not sure if this does what I think it does:  

`git merge -s recursive -X theirs OtherGuysBranchWithResolutions`

Does this actually do what I need or are there gotchas?

Comment: you can perform a sort of "dry run" and check what the merge is going to do, as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
git checkout master
git merge -Xtheirs otherbranch
```

Comment: I had found this mere moments before your answer, and was wondering if it is what I need or is there some gotcha. So far it appears to be what I want though.