# git: Solve merge conflicts without performing a merge

Tags: git

I just want to know, if there is any way, to resolve merge commits, of two git branches, without actually merging them.

Assuming, I  have a branch "featureMy"; my colleague created another branch "featureHis". Both branches are created on "master" branch.

My colleague then created a merge request for his branch "featureHis" into master. When I then create my merge request of "featureMy" into master, I want to ensure, that it will not conflicts with master after "featureHis" is merged.

Usually, I will merge "featureHis" into "featureMy" before. However, this is not that satisfying, because I have a additional merge commit as "noise" and my merge request will contain changes from "featureHis".

Is there a way, so that I can solve the merge conflicts, without creating a merge commit?

Kind regards

Comment: You could do `--no-commit` if you want to see if there will be a conflict. http://stackoverflow.com/a/501461/3000179

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One standard way to avoid having merge commits is to use rebasing in place of merging.  Consider the following scenario:

```
master:     A
featureMy:  A -- B
featureHis: A -- C
```

Assuming that only these two branches are extant from `master`, then one of you will merge with `master` first.  Let's say it is your colleague who gets there first.  Then the diagram would look like this:

```
master:     A -- C
featureMy:  A -- B
featureHis: A -- C
```

Your colleague's commit is now in the `master` branch.  Now if you use a merge-based workflow, you would first merge `master` into your branch, and then you merge your branch back into `master`.  This would result in:

```
master:     A -- C -- E
featureMy:  A -- B -- D
featureHis: A -- C
```

Now both your branch *and* the `master` branch have ugly merge commits in them.  However, if you had *rebased* your branch on `master`, you would be left with:

```
master:     A -- C
featureMy:  A -- C -- B'    (B' indicates that this a new commit, not B)
featureHis: A -- C
```

Now your branch `featureMy` is actually *ahead* of the `master` branch.  You can simply push your commit in, directly on top of `master`, with no conflicts.  This results in the following diagram:

```
master:     A -- C -- B'
featureMy:  A -- C -- B'
featureHis: A -- C
```

Notice that there are *no* merge commits anywhere.  In fact, both your `featureMy` branch and `master` have *identical* linear histories.

Long live `git rebase`.

Comment: I would add that in order to follow his current workflow, he should first rebase branch `featureMy` onto `featureHis` and resolve any conflicts. After branch `featureHis` is merged into `master`, he can rebase `featureMy` onto `master` and merge to `master`.

Comment: Unfortunately, very rarely it is a real-life scenario. Most of the time `featureHis` and `featureMy` are remote branches, thus re-base will be disastrous and will not work.

Comment: What if all I want is `A -- B'` without the `C` in `featureHis`??

Comment: "if you don't want to use a rusty hammer to bang in a nail, you can always punch it with your fist"

Comment: @Isaac It's a great and detailed answer. But nice attempt at spreading FUD about rebase. Many teams work exactly like this answer describes and have a clean and sequential git history without noisy merge commits as a result.

Comment: @timotgl "those pesky logs, just delete them!" sometimes verbosity is good :)

Answer (score 9):

If your merge conflicts can be solved by using one version of a file entirely, here's a solution.

Say you want to merge into a branch called `qa` and there are conflicts in  `composer.json` and `composer.lock`. `qa` contains later versions that you want to use instead of what's in your branch.

```
git checkout origin/qa -- composer.json composer.lock
git commit -m "fixed merge conflicts without merging"
```

Comment: Can you elaborate for 2 local branches, b1 & b2?