# How to resolve git conflict locally (with some constraints)?

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

**I want to resolve a git merge conflict (between *feature* and *test* branches), but there are some limitations:**

1. cannot push directly to *test* and *master* branches
2. cannot merge *feature* branch into the *test* branch (because I cannot push to *origin test*)
3. cannot merge *test* branch into the *feature* branch (because later, when it is tested I should merge *feature* branch into the *master* branch)
4. the conflict is caused by the *test* branch NOT the *master* branch
5. I want to avoid duplicating branches
6. cannot resolve conflict on Gitlab UI, because it merge the target branch (*test*) into the source branch (*feature*) after resolving

The workflow of my team is the following:

- every **feature** branch must be **based on *master*** branch
- commit/push the *feature* branch then **create a merge request to *test* (*default*) branch** (then wait for testing)
- **create a merge request to *master*** branch

I tried with these workarounds:

1. turn off the "anti-push" constraint temporarily (if there are a lot of conflicts, this is not ideal)
2. turn off the "anti-push" constraint permanently (I do not want this...)
3. using duplicated branches (I do not want this, because it is confusing)
4. using Gitlab UI (break my workflow, mentioned above)
5. manually edit the feature branch (does not work, because it is not a "real" merge)

I think I cannot use `git rebase`, because the conflict is not caused by the *master* branch, and I want to preserve the "master based" feature branch, so I also cannot use rebase based on *test* branch.

In few cases, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64810110/7742526) can solve the problem, but not in my case.

**I am looking for a "simple" solution which resolve the problem above.**
*Temporary branches on local (but not on remote) are okay.*

Answer (score 1):

**Heavily Updated Answer**

After reading the problem more closely and also agreeing with sentiments expressed by @j6t I need to alter my advice... this workflow as a whole is problematic.   Don't do what I said ( don't branch feature from `test` ).  Branch from master, then make a variant of the branch called `feature-test` which you create in case of a conflict by doing one of the two conflict resolution paths i mentioned ( merge feature into test, or test into feature and resolve the conflicts ) and that branch can be requested for merge to `test`.. if items come up make fixes to your initial branch and then merge that branch into `feature-test` again.   this way you keep fixes found from testing in `feature` in `feature` and you keep conflict resolutions in `feature-test`, so that in the end you can merge `feature` to `master`, with stronger safety that fixes of issues from `feature`'s testing are in `feature` but not conflict resoultion or stray materials from `test`.

My big issue with this is that `test` shouldn't generally exist or be used. They should test your branch by merging `master` into it and testing it.  Otherwise what you are testing is not what you are merging to master, and it doesnt sound like testing is performed on master.

Now if you have a bunch of related features, or you have a big change such that other things SHOULD be aware of and take account for it things change. In that case you should use an integration branch that you merge into for testing, and you should potentially branch off the `integration` branch for the features that are targeted for the `integration` branch, which will all go to `master` together.

Overall if `test` is not merged to `master` but you test off of it, and you keep fixing things on `test` you end up in a wierd state where you aren't testing what will actually go to `master` which could both hide and introduce bugs that you would otherwise catch in testing.

Some things I said before still hold:

- There is no SIMPLE solution for resolving merge conflicts; you have to resolve them manually otherwise git would have done it for you.
- The workflow and constraints make this a horrible situation.  They are effectively testing a branch can significantly vary from what master will be.
- I honestly don't see value from the `test` branch currently, if `test` is not merged to `master` and vice `versa`, and only see negatives stemming from it.

Personally if this was the workflow I was presented with I would be discussing changing it, or heading toward a new job unless there is significant test automation that is carried out by CI/CD before the branch is allowed to merge to `master`.  It's a recipe for disaster.  You're going to constantly be wasting time crafting conflict resolutions to be able to merge to `test` that are thrown away, and then possibly doing different resolutions to merge to `master`.

The testers should do their testing and have automation in place on your branch once its PR is opened to be merged to master.  They should mark it passed when they have validated it.  I would do this by having two different sets of gatekeeper approvals required for the merge to master, someone from code review group, and someone from qa ( if that can't be done via CI/CD ).

- Whoever is in the appropriate leadership role, to be deciding which changes should be merged when, should be initiating the merges to `master` once a `feature` is both validated (reviewed and tested) and desired to be brought into `master`.
- If a `feature` is validated and sits because it's not yet wanted in `master`, than it sits there ready and waiting.
- If additional commits go to the `feature` after testing, the testing needs to be verified again (this is why automation/CI/CD is best), and someone should update the code review to approve it again.
- Finally, there should also be a run of the testing on `master` commits to make sure that if something is independently added to `master` that didn't conflict with `feature` that the two both being present doesn't cause a problem.

It also boils down to goals: should `master` always be deployable? Or should it always be buildable, mostly stable, where you work from, and periodically you cut a release from `master` that has been more deeply tested? ( In which case you should absolutely tag a release commit so that patches can be created on top of the released version, and then ported/merged/cherry-picked as needed to `master`.  There is no right or wrong answer to this question.  Different projects/workflows and scenarios have different requirements.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Your observation is reasonable, we may branching from test instead of master, but there are a lot of bug/feature which require a lot of time. We do not want to wait for all of them, we need to deploy "small" chunks, instead of "complete" release. That's why we are branching on master.

Comment: @MárkMatuz Don't branch feature branches from test! You will regret it. Generally, the requirement to begin feature branches from a stable upstream like master is very sensible. With this workflow rule, all features that are under development have a stable basis and do not have to aim at a moving target.

Comment: @j6t I have changed my mind between your comment and reading the question more carefully.. I agree with you completely.  I have updated my answer accordingly.   I was under the mistaken impression that `test` was being merged into `master` which it is not.  (because not doing that to me makes `test` make no sense at all ) That of course is a game changer..

Answer (score 0):

I'd still suggest rebasing `feature` branch onto `test`: you can later rebase the result back onto `master` (possibly making that easier if the conflicting features from `test` get merged onto master, too).

On the other hand, if the conflicting changes in `test` are temporary (i.e, won't be merged to master) then just create a copy of your `feature` branch (e.g `feature-test`) and rebase *that copy* onto `test` and do the testing that you want. And when you add new commits, you can use either `feature` or `feature-test`, whichever is more convenient, and then cherry-pick the commits into the other one as well.