# Git diff: show only conflicting lines without making a merge

Tags: git, diff

Suppose I have two branches `master` and `feature`, and I'm currently on `feature`.
I don't need to merge these branches, but I want to know amount of conflicts which can give the possible merge.
More accurately I want `git diff` to show only those lines (or only their amount if I'll give `--stat` option), which will give conflicts if I'll decide to make a merge.
I know about `--diff-filter=U` option which gives me following workaround:

```
git merge master --no-ff --no-commit
git diff --diff-filter=U -U0     #|grep "@@@"  #if i want only number of conflicted lines
git merge --abort
```

But this solution has some disadvantages:

1. It can't be applied if there are uncommitted changes on `feature`
2. It's too long and to alias it I need to write much longer script, which will treat different situations like uncommitted changes (using `stash`) or wrong name for branch to compare (exiting script) or that I'm already in merging state before running the script, etc.

It there a more elegant solution than long aliased script which fakes merging (it is the root of the problems above)?

Comment: I don't think it can be done without invoking merge, or something equivalent (e.g., `git merge-file` for each file). If there are uncommitted changes, commit them first, on an anonymous branch; then do the merge itself, on the same anonymous branch; then reset back to the commit you just made (use `--allow-empty` to make one even if there are no uncommitted files) and then do a soft reset back to the original branch/commit.

Comment: A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option).