# Making sure that "git merge origin aBranch" is working as expected

Tags: git, git-merge

**Local-Branches**

- BranchA
- FrozenBranch
- master

**Commands**

```
git checkout BranchA
git merge origin FrozenBranch
```

**Expectaion** : I am running this command and expecting that all the changes from remote FrozenBranch will be applied to local BranchA

**Please, let me know that if the outcome is something else. I am trying to make sure that this does not merge my remote master to Frozen Branch**

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option

Comment: You just said that `FrozenBranch` is a *local* branch (in the first part of the question), then used the adjective *remote* (in the second part). Git's terminology is a mess, so while there is no such thing as a "remote branch", there *is* a *remote-tracking branch* (which is not remote, it's locally-stored, and is not a branch, so it's really poorly named!) but it would be spelled `origin/FrozenBranch`, not `FrozenBranch`. In any case you definitely *do not* want to pass two names `origin<space>FrozenBranch` to `git merge`.

Comment: I am just trying to make sure that `git merge origin FrozenBranch` does not merge my master branch into FrozenBranch.

Answer (score 1):

Probably should do `git merge origin/FrozenBranch` but yes, it will work as you want. You will not hurt frozenbranch unless you push to frozen branch. When you push make sure you do something like `git push origin BranchA:BranchA`

Comment: When I run git merge origin FrozenBranch, "origin" is referring to remote FrozenBranch right?

Comment: yes, but do a `git fetch --all` first to make sure everything is up to date