# How to detect whether git pull would fail due to untracked local files?

Tags: git

Git rightly gives an error when you do a `git pull` when the commit(s) merged would create a file that you have locally but is not tracked.

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge

**I would like to detect this situation in a script so that I can do something about it before doing the git pull for real.**

How can I do this? I tried `git pull --dry-run` but annoyingly that does not notice that the pull would fail (git version 2.11.0)

### Test

```
mkdir a b; cd a
git init .; echo hi >file1 ; git add .; git commit -m "initial commit"
cd ../
git clone a b
cd a; echo boo>file2; git add .; git commit -m "2nd commit"
cd ../b
echo xxx>file2
git fetch

if some_git_command_detects_pull_would_fail
then
  echo 'Uh oh!'
fi
```

Nb. I realise I can "clean" out untracked files; that untracked files are nasty; that I can stash changes etc. but this is not what I want.

Comment: Never use `git pull` in scripts. (Well, hardly ever. Recursive fetch-and-merge, with submodules, is ugly. But pull is very porcelain, not at all plumbing-friendly.)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's an interactive script that saves me typing; not an automated process.

Comment: Even then, just break it into fetch + merge. You'll know if the merge would fail because the merge fails. You can back the merge out if it succeeds (or use `--no-commit` as in the answer I've upvoted), if that's part of the general plan.

Answer (score 1):

`git pull` is a shortcut for : `git fetch` + `git merge`

One way to "detect" before applying pull  is :

- run `git fetch`
- check if some files in the remote branch would clash with existing files on your disk :

  - run `git merge --no-commit` with the upstream branch

    ```
    # if current branch is "linked" to a remote branch,
    # @{u} is a shortcut to say "the linked remote branch"
    git merge --no-commit @{u}

    # or you can explicitly name the remote reference :
    git merge --no-commit origin/you/know/what/branch
    ```
  - see if this action triggers any errors or merge conflicts
  - revert to what it was previously :

    ```
    git merge --abort
    ```

---

Another way to check "would this merge create conflicts ?" is offered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6339869/86072)

Comment: I guess it's that 2nd bullet point I'm not clear on how to do

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [LeGEC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54705708/623519)'s hint, I've found something that appears to work:

```
function merge_will_work {
  git diff master..origin/master | git apply --check &>/dev/null
  return $?
}
```

- Creates the patch
- Tests whether it would apply cleanly
- (Importantly) does not change a single file either way. (avoids a merge/merge abort situation where files may be momentarily changed.)