# How can i get there would be conflict if you merge two branch usign git command

Tags: git, git-merge

I am trying to merge two branch without conflict in my script. but if there is any conflict i do not want to fire git merge command, merge two branch. 
So is anyway that i can check before fire merge command there is any conflict or not?

Comment: Do you want to do this manually or in a script?

Comment: through git command using in script

Comment: You can see it in GitHub by creating a merge request.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a git-merge --dry-run option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+merge+conflict+without+merge

Answer (score 4):

Manually, the naive route might be to

```
# actually do the merge
git merge <target>
```

Then, either it's a conflict, in which case you :

```
git merge --abort
```

...or it's not, and you just undo your commit :

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

and you're back in step 1 in both cases, the merge undone, and you have your answer to the question "Will this be a conflict?".

And YES I find it clunky too but hey! it works. (and to be fair, with aliases it can be very practical)

Comment: actully merge and reset takes time in script.
so i want the way that before merge i can check any conflict if not then i merge 
if conflict i dont want to merge\

Comment: Yeah, that was the point of my earlier question about *manual* or *scripting*. This is an answer for manual action.

Comment: @paraschauhan - Well, "want" and "can" are two different things.  `git` does not provide a "dry run" for merging, so what you'd have to do (afaik) is (1) diff `HEAD` against the merge base; (2) diff the merge target against the merge base; (3) compare the patches to look for overlapping/adjacent change hunks.  That's reproducing most of the work of the merge, though it *might* be faster for lack of actually updating the work tree.  But that said...

Comment: @paraschauhan - You say that if there's no conflict, you do actually want to do the merge.  So if you leave out the `reset` when the merge is successful, and otherwise follow the above process, then the only time when the script "wastes" time is when there's a conflict - which for most projects is relatively rare