# GitHub Actions, detect conflict in merge

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I am trying to check/validate if a `git merge` would cause conflicts in GitHub Actions. If the validation is successful, the workflow should actually merge and push the changes, or else the workflow stops.

Merge should be done from master to develop branch.

Part of my code is:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --no-commit --no-ff master
echo '::set-output name=mergeResult::$?'
git merge --abort
```

I am reading the value of `mergeResult` variable. If 0, proceed with the actual merge; if 1, stop the workflow and echo a message.

In case there are no conflicts, everything works fine. However, when there is a merge conflict, the workflow run fails:

> CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in somefile.txt
> Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
> Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

My question is: How to avoid this error and let the workflow resume with no failure, regardless of merge conflicts.

Comment: If one command fails, the whole workflow fails.

Comment: No workaround at all? A way to avoid failure and just validate the merge result?

Comment: What about [`continue-on-error`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepscontinue-on-error)?

Comment: You could try `--no-commit`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/501461/3266847

Comment: @dan1st Thank you! That solved :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a git-merge --dry-run option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option)