# Git merge-base and merge-tree in python

Tags: python, git, gitpython

I am working on a python script to automatically sync my workspace if possible and need to judge if I can rebase my changes on top of remote master changes.

I am trying to use the brilliant answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/6283843/965830

I want to run the following commands :

1. Fetch the remote to your repository. For example: `git fetch origin master`
2. Run git merge-base: `git merge-base FETCH_HEAD master`
3. Run git merge-tree: `git merge-tree mergebase master FETCH_HEAD` (mergebase is the hexadecimal id that merge-base printed in the previous step)

For command 1, I am using the following successfully

```
gitRepo = git.Repo(abspath);
gitRepo.remotes.origin.fetch(refspec="master")
```

However, I am not able to find any documentation for `merge-base` and `merge-tree` commands.

------Edit

Found this documentation of `merge-tree` : https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html?highlight=merge-tree#git.index.base.IndexFile.merge_tree

How can I write this in a way that it doesn't actually perform the merge.

Comment: Why write this in python when it's much easier to write it as a shell script?

Comment: I have other parts of the script which would need arrays to keep track of all the repositories and workspaces. That was becoming quite troublesome in shell.

Comment: OK. Remember that you can always spin off a Git command with `subprocess`. Most Git commands that produce program-digestible output have a `-z` or similar option to produce usable byte streams. `git merge-tree` does not, but it's not really used any more. Aside from routine maintenance the last update to it was in 2013. You might be better off using a temporary index and `git read-tree` directly.