Resolve conflict with VSCode in the merging branch before merging
I'm using VSCode to resolve merging conflicts, but I've noticed that it uses the "standard" auto-merge option. When you have resolved all the conflicts, it creates a commit with all the resolved conflicts and merges it.
I would like to still use the merge edit in VSCode to fix the conflicts, commit them in the merging branch, and then merge it with its own commit when the margin branch has no conflicts.
Is that a thing that's possible?
This is what I would like to do
|
°\  merge commit
| |
| ° commit fix merge conflict using merge editor in VSCode
|\| trying the merge but conflicts arise
| |
1 2

This is what VSCode does
|
°\  commit fix conflict on VSCode merge editor and merges
| |
|\| trying the merge but conflicts arise
| |
1 2

On the above graph, branch 1 is develop and branch 2 is my feature-branch

I didn't understand how what you describe VS Code is doing now is different from what you would like it to do. Is the graph you show what it currently does or what you want?

@mkrieger1 that's what I want. What it currently does is just generating the merge commit

Okay, then that's just what Git does, and you want VS Code to do something in addition. I'm not sure if VS Code can do that, but here's a starting point for how you can do it using the Git command-line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501407/is-there-a-git-merge-dry-run-option
